# Setting up and using zlib properly

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm playing around with `zlib` and after reading the [zlib_how](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) I still have couple of questions. As I understand, the `deflateInit` should be called before calling any `deflate()` which is ok, but what happens when I have an intention to reuse the same stream more than once?

Should I call `deflateEnd` each time I finish compression and then reinitialize every time the compression is called with additional call to the `deflateInit`? Whats about internal buffers dynamic allocations?

I see that init and end malloc/free a lot, could it be configured in such a way internal buffers will be reused between calls?

Comment: Downvoting without giving a reason? Very helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `deflateReset()` instead of `deflateEnd()` followed by `deflateInit()`, in order to avoid unnecessary `free()`'s and `malloc()`'s.

You should also read the documentation in zlib.h, where you would have discovered this.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Is deflateReset() good for being called in case of Z_STREAM_ERROR after deflate() was called? instead of deflateEnd? and what should I do in case the deflateReset() returns Z_STREAM_ERROR? Call deflateEnd() followed by deflateInit()?

Comment: If you get `Z_STREAM_ERROR` then that state was either never initialized, ended, or corrupted. For any of those you should _not_ call either `deflateEnd()` or `deflateReset()`, since the state is no longer valid. (Though those are also likely to notice that and return `Z_STREAM_ERROR` as well.) If you use zlib properly, i.e. initializing, resetting, and ending in the proper order, and you never inadvertently write over the state, then you will never get a `Z_STREAM_ERROR`.

Comment: It is a very important note. Thanks again!